# Issue with ark4random and exit code 1 IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I am using Cocos2D to develop and app and it seems that I have hit a snag with this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
 "_ark4random", referenced from:
  -[HelloWorldLayer addMonster] in HelloWorldLayer.o
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"
```

The code that it seems to effect is:

```
-(void)addMonster {
CCSprite *monster = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"monster.png"];
// Determine where to spawn the monster along the Y axis
CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
int minY = monster.contentSize.height / 2;
int maxY = winSize.height - monster.contentSize.height/2;
int rangeY = maxY - minY;
int actualY = (arc4random() % rangeY) + minY;

// Create the monster slightly off-screen along the right edge,
// and along a random position along the Y axis as calculated above

monster.position = ccp(winSize.width + monster.contentSize.width/2, actualY);
[self addChild:monster];

// Determine the speed of the monster
int minDuration = 2.0;
int maxDuration = 4.0;
int rangeDuration = maxDuration - minDuration;
**int actualDuration = (ark4random() % rangeDuration) + minDuration;**

// Create the actions
CCMoveTo *actionMove = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:actualDuration
        position:ccp(-monster.contentSize.width/2, actualY)];
CCCallBlockN *actionMoveDone = [CCCallBlockN actionWithBlock:^(CCNode *node) {
    [node removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
}];
[monster runAction:[CCSequence actions:actionMove, actionMoveDone, nil]];

 }
// on "dealloc" you need to release all your retained objects
 - (void) dealloc
 {
// in case you have something to dealloc, do it in this method
// in this particular example nothing needs to be released.
// cocos2d will automatically release all the children (Label)

// don't forget to call "super dealloc"
[super dealloc];
}
```

The line of code with the stars around it is the one with the issue I believe.  THANKS!

Comment: Didn't the compiler show some warning in the "ark4random" line?

Comment: There isn't such a think called ark4random..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a simple syntax error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message says it all.
Did you try using:

```
int actualDuration = (arc4random() % rangeDuration) + minDuration;
```

instead of

```
int actualDuration = (ark4random() % rangeDuration) + minDuration;
```

Comment: Thank you!  I feel so dumb right now haha.